# Values not getting saved in the Excel for a looping script in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Please find the below script. Planning to save the Id and Name fields in excel.I am not seeing the values getting stored in the excel in series. Instead the  previous values are getting displayed in the excel inside a loop call. Please help me by posting your suggestion. Thanks in Advance

Script:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
def run():
    from selenium import webdriver
    from texttable import len
    import xlrd
    import xlwt
    driver=webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get("http://ssmatri.com/ssnmlprofilelist.php?type=GO")
    driver.maximize_window()
    w1=driver.window_handles[0]
    try:
        while (driver.find_element_by_link_text("1").text=='1'):
            try:
                #driver.find_element_by_id("withphoto").click()
                j=(len("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr/td"))
                driver.implicitly_wait(20)
                for i in range (2,j+1):
                    name= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[3]"%i).text
                    print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[3]"%i).text
                    Id= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[2]"%i).text
                    print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[2]"%i).text
                    #print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[5]/h5"%i).text
                    print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]"%i).text
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='p7']/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/table[4]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]"%i).click()
                    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
                    w2=driver.window_handles[1]
                    driver.switch_to_window(w2)
                    #print driver.current_url
                    print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtByJquery']/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]").text
                    print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtByJquery']/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]").text
                    k=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtByJquery']/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[3]").text
                    print k
                    if(k=='H1B Visa'):
                        print 'The person holds passport and H1B Visa'
                    elif(k=="Passport Holder"):
                        print 'The Person holds Passport but does not hold H1B Visa'
                    else:
                        print 'The person does not hold Passport and Visa'
                    driver.close()
                    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
                    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
                    book=xlwt.Workbook()
                    sheet1=book.add_sheet("Matchings")
                    sheet1.write(i,0,name)
                    sheet1.write(i,1,Id)
                    book.save('C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\saisankara_Matchings.xls')
                    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
                    continue
            except NoSuchElementException:
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            if(driver.find_element_by_link_text("next>>").text=='next>>'):
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("next>>").click()
            elif driver.find_element_by_link_text("1").text=='1' :
                driver.find_element_by_link_text("1")
                #driver.find_element_by_link_text("1").click()
            continue
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you create and save the workbook **within** your loop - it's  overwriting each previously created and saved file in next iteration.

Comment: Ok. But the value of i varies for each row right then how it can be overridden ?.Can you share me the solution if you have any ?

Comment: Create `book` and `sheet1` outside the loop, as well as `save` them after looping operation.

Comment: ...as well as keeping outside a reference to the `row` which should be written to. 
Increase after writing the data. 

I tried your code, there are depreciated calls and an exception:

`w2=driver.window_handles[1]` 
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Please debug your code  yourself

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think so the looping doesn't matter. Here is an example for an for loop with excel. For this code the values are getting saved in the excel.                                                                                book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("sample")
for i in range(10):
    sheet1.write(i,i,i)
    book.save('C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\ex.xls')
print 'The script is completed'

Comment: Please debug yourself.
Last example, creation of workbook is outside the loop.

Values are written here, but there are other bugs